# ipython notebook view wide pandas dataframe vertically

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In Pandas 0.18.1, say I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,200))
df.head()

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
```

What if I wanted to view this vertically like so:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 11
```

the docs point to:

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)

df

0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0 -1.039575  0.271860 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401 -0.673690   
1  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312   
2  1.643563 -1.469388  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914 -1.294524   
3 -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061  0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412   
4 -1.170299 -0.226169  0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467   

      7         8         9  
0  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988  
1  0.844885  1.075770 -0.109050  
2  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035  
3  2.565646  1.431256  1.340309  
4 -1.187678  1.130127 -1.436737
```

Yet I can't seem to get that same result; what am I missing?

Previous questions seem to revolve around viewing all rows within the slider (`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` sort of thing)

Comment: Could you transpose it or do you want to wrap the columns?

Comment: I just want to wrap it basically; the way 'expand_frame_repr' seems to do it in the docs

Comment: You could try pd.reset_option('all'), then set all other. It sets all options default.

Comment: same result after a pd.reset_option('all')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',100)

print(df)
```

Comment: If you have  IPython.display import display imported it will not work by just calling it you will print into a typical dataframe format. Use the print() without calling the Ipython display then it should work.  I re altered my solution above try it again!

Comment: the print (df) as opposed to simply 'df' seems to make all the diffference; thank you

is there not a way to do this and keep the tabular style?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to see just a few records, try this.

```
df.head(3).transpose()
```